# Como fazer um DataGrid em HTML5?

Tags: php, html5, css3

Boa tarde, eu queria saber como se faz um DataGrid em HTML5 mais ou menos 
parecido com o da imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma tabela? Ou precisa das funções que o datagrid contem? Se for com as funcionalidades, você precisa fazer uma tabela e implementar as funcionalidades em javascript.

Comment: Preciso fazer um DataGrid para receber registros que forem registrados no banco de dados.

Comment: Que linguagem você está usando no backend? Asp.net?

Comment: No backend eu estou usando php, eu quero fazer um DataGrid em html5 e php mais ou menos igual ao Asp.net @DiegoMoreira , obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: Rapaz, em php é mais fácil. Mesmo esquema do que te falei como resposta \/. Boa sorte. :)

Comment: Obrigado @DiegoMoreira :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em todo caso, pra você montar um DataGrid em Html, você vai precisar fazer um foreach nos valores.

**Exemplo**

```
// header da tabela
string tabPedidos = "";
tabPedidos += "<table class='table table-bordered'><tr>";
tabPedidos += "<td>#</td>";
tabPedidos += "<td>Status:</td>";
tabPedidos += "<td>Valor:</td>";
tabPedidos += "<td>Data (R$):</td>";
tabPedidos += "<td></td>";
tabPedidos += "</tr>";

// no caso, pego os valores via DataSet
PedidoFuncs ped = new PedidoFuncs();
DataSet ds = ped.GetPedidos();

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

// foreach nos valores
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        // atribuindo valores para as variaveis
        int codPed = Int32.Parse(ds.Tables[i].Rows[j]["ID"].ToString());
        string dataHora = ds.Tables[i].Rows[j]["DATAHORA"].ToString();
        string valPed = ds.Tables[i].Rows[j]["VALOR"].ToString();
        string statusPed = ds.Tables[i].Rows[j]["STATUS"].ToString();
        string resultPed = "";
        string classPed = "";

        if (statusPed == "1")
        {
            resultPed = "Aprovado";
            classPed = "success";
        } 
        else if (statusPed == "0")
        {
            resultPed = "Aguardando aprovação";
            classPed = "warning";
        }
        else if (statusPed == "2")
        {
            resultPed = "Pagamento cancelado";
            classPed = "danger";
        }
        else if (statusPed == "-1")
        {
            resultPed = "Não Aprovado";
            classPed = "danger";
        }

        // alimentando a tabela
        tabPedidos += "<tr class='" + classPed + "'>";
        tabPedidos += "<td>" + codPed + "</td>";
        tabPedidos += "<td>" + resultPed + "</td>";
        tabPedidos += "<td>R$ " + valPed + "</td>";
        tabPedidos += "<td>" + dataHora + "</td>";
        tabPedidos += "<td><a href='Pedido.aspx?id=" + codPed + "' class='btn btn-primary'>Visualizar</a></td>";
        tabPedidos += "</tr>";
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
tabPedidos += "</table>"; // fechando a tabela

divPedidos.InnerHtml = tabPedidos; //publicando a tabela dentro de uma div
```

Answer (score 1):

Não existe um componente datagrid no HTML, você tem que criar utilizando uma tabela, na linguagem que você estiver desenvolvendo.

Aqui você encontra alguns em javascript:
[15 JavaScript Data Grids to Enhance your HTML Tables](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/15-javascript-data-grids-enhance-html-tables/)

Existem também opções pagas, como este para ASP.NET MVC
[Telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index)

Comment: Obrigado por essa valiosa informação @WashingtondaCosta :)